# Get the index of a usercontrol in a control array at runtime

Tags: user-controls, vb6

So I've got a usercontrol.
In the form, I have a control array of these usercontrols. Each instance of the control has an index set in the designer.

I want, at runtime, to get the index of a specific usercontrol (this is in the context of a For Each loop). However, "index" is not a member of the UserControl class. How do I make it so I can get the index at runtime?

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
for each UserControl in UserControls
    OtherArray(UserControl.index) = UserControl.value
next UserControl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Index` property is a member of the `Control` and `Extender` objects, but NOT the user controls.

<strike>You can get the index by typing the variable correctly:</strike>

```
Dim UserControl As MyUserControlType
Dim UserControl2 As Control

For Each UserControl In UserControls
    Set UserControl2 = UserControl
    OtherArray(UserControl2.index) = UserControl.value
Next UserControl
```

You still need a variable of your user control type to access the `Value` property.

The former method no longer works.

As the user control can access its `Index` through its `Extender` object, you can add an additional property that the caller can use:

```
Public Property Get MyIndex() As Long
  MyIndex = Extender.Index
End Property
```

And this to access it:

```
Dim MyUserControlInstance As MyUserControl
Dim OtherArray() As String
ReDim OtherArray(0 To 3)

For Each MyUserControlInstance In MyUserControlArray
    OtherArray(MyUserControlInstance.MyIndex) = MyUserControlInstance.Value
Next MyUserControlInstance
```

Comment: Oh, for a language with a sane inheritance system.
Thanks for the answer I was looking for however.

Comment: So I accepted this, impying it worked for me. But trying it now, I get "datatype mismatch" error on the line `set usercontrol2 = usercontrol`

Comment: Only a year late.. :) On testing it here, I get the same result. I may have broken it while sanitising my post. One moment...

Comment: @CMaster I've added an alternative method as I can't get my original one to work.

Comment: Great, thanks, that works. I now know about the extender object too.

Answer (score 0):

Most controls in VB6 have a Tag property. (It's been a while, so I don't remember if User Controls have this property as well.)

If they do, you could set the Tag property to the same value as the array index, in the form designer.

If User Controls don't have a Tag property, you could loop through the array at program startup and set the Tag property of one of the controls inside each User Control. For example, pick some Label or TextBox control to hold the "Tag" property for the entire Uset Control.

Comment: Well, it being a usercontrol, I can give it a tag property (or an "ActualIndex" or whatever). Just wondered if there was a better way, especially as Usercontrols(I).index is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop and access them by index:

```
For I = UserControls.LBound To UserControls.UBound
  'Use I as the index here
Next
```

Note that if the array is not contiguous (Some indexes in the middle are not loaded) you will need to detect the error and skip to the next item.

Comment: Not safe because for various reasons the control array may not have all values between those two bounds. Also for control arrays, the correct format would be usercontrols.Ubound . ubound(usercontrls) doesn't work with control arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a small improvement on the code above:

If the UserControl is not in an array, Extender.Index causes an error.
MyIndex returns -1 if the Usercontrol is not in an array.

Public Property Get MyIndex() As Long

On Error GoTo NotAnArrayNoIndexError

MyIndex = Extender.Index

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Property

NotAnArrayNoIndexError:

On Error GoTo 0

MyIndex = -1

End Property

Answer (score -2):

What about the "name" Property. In the ControlsCollection every Control has a name.

```
dim i as long
dim found as boolean
for i = lBound(OtherArray) to uBound(OtherArray)
  for each UserControl in UserControls
    if OtherArray(i).name = UserControl.name then
      found = true
      exit for
    end if
    next UserControl
  if found then exit for
next UserControl
```

Comment: The name will be the same for all controls in a control array. You should use `Is` to check if object instances are the same.